# Does RSpec destroy FactoryGirl created objects after every it block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an `it` block with the following

```
it 'creates a new post' do
  post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
end

it 'accesses a post' do
  expect(Post.count).to eq(1)
end
```

I am not using database cleaner. Does post gets automatically destroyed after each test case?

Comment: no - that's why there is the database cleaner gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with defaults, then you probably have this in your `rails_helper.rb`:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

This wraps each of your test in a DB transaction, so that changes in one test do not affect another. So, to answer your question: Yes, with your code, the post in the first test will not exist in the second.

If you want a `post` to exist for all tests, within a `context`, you should add this line to the `context`:

```
let!(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post) }
```

or, if you do not need to access the `post`, and simply need it there in the DB:

```
before do
  FactoryGirl.create(:post)
end
```